# Error: Callback function is not available with promise clients

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise

I am using the following function(that initially was written in JS and I tried to convert it to TS) to create a new record on `mysql`:

```
class Post{
  title = "";
  body = "";
  constructor(title: string, body: string) {
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
  }

   save(): Promise<IPost> {
    const d = new Date();
    const yyyy = d.getFullYear();
    const mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
    const dd = d.getDate();

    const createdAtDate = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;

    const sql = `
    INSERT INTO posts(
      title,
      body,
      created_at
    )
    VALUES(
      '${this.title}',
      '${this.body}',
      '${createdAtDate}'
    )
    `;

    return new Promise<IPost>((resolve, reject) => {
      db.execute<OkPacket>(sql, (err: Error, res: Response) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          console.log(err);
        }
        else resolve(res.json())
      });
    });
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Callback function is not available with promise clients.
```

How should I update the function to resolve the problem? Also please let me know if more information is needed.

EDIT: This is the `db.ts` file:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import mysql from "mysql2";

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
});

export default pool.promise();
```

Comment: Did you look at `execute` function documentation? Isn't it a Promise-like?

Comment: @Anatoly: I was onlu following a Youtube video to learn how to connect Node application to `mysql` and this code was written in JS and when I tried to convert it to TS this problem happened. I don't know much about `execute` function and just wanted to test it for the first time.

Comment: It might be that the version of `mysql` package in the video was much older than the one you installed and they replaced callback-based `execute` with Promise-based one by default. Did you install the same exact versions of packages that were shown in the video?

Comment: @AnatolyL No I just did `npm i mysql2` and it might has installed the latest version. So do you mean the `execute` function nos is deprecated and I must totally change it? Could you upgrade my code to the latest version that it works? I'm just a new learner and want to make it work.

Comment: @Anatoly: I also added the `db` file's content maybe it works.

Comment: You used `pool.promise();` that's why you need to use promised version of `execute`. Either use just `pool` or get rid of `callback` and use `await` to get the result of `execute`

Comment: @Anatoly: I see in most of the codes they use `query` instead of `execute`. What is the difference?

Comment: Look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#documentation the section "Using Prepared Statements"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add TS extension(s) to your IDE in order to highlight some common ts errors, changing js file to ts should not introduce any functional difference

Comment: Could you introduce a good extension to install?

Comment: ESLint will be a great option, TSLint has been deprecated in favor of it. I'll go for ESLint

Comment: I added the extension and reloaded my VSCODE but no new errors or warnings on codes it does show and the error is same as before from the server.